# Converting the threads array to task and getting the name or task ID

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I had thread arrays in my code  which I am going to replace with task.

```
 Dictionary<string, name> threadnames = new Dictionary<string, name>();
 public Thread [] Threads;
 string[] nodeKeys;

 for (int i = 0; i < nodeKeys.Length; i++)
 {
   Threads[i] = new Thread(() => ThreadMethod(nodeKey));
   Threads[i].Name = nodeKey[i];
   names.Add(Threads[i].Name, null);
   Threads[i].Start();
 }
```

This was the old approach in which I was also saving my thread names in a separate dictionary. Now I am going to convert it to task what so far I have done is this

```
 Dictionary<string, name> threadnames = new Dictionary<string, name>();
 string[] nodeKeys;

 for (int i = 0; i < nodeKeys.Length; i++)
 {
  var runningTask = new Task(() => ThreadMethod(nodeKey[i]));
  runningTask.Start();
 }
```

Now since all is in for loop, should all of this be done in single task? Or if the above is right approach what about the task id I have to get?

Or if there is better approach to do it will be appreciated.

Comment: If you need to keep track of the tasks, why don't you simply add them to a `List<Task>`? Why do you need a name or an id?

Comment: Thats because i have to keep its track in separate dictionary .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Task` has no concept of a name. But since you seem to create a `Task` per `string` in your `nodeKeys` array, you could use this `string` as the key provided that it is unique:

```
Dictionary<string, Task> tasks = new Dictionary<string, Task>();
string[] nodeKeys;

for (int i = 0; i<nodeKeys.Length; i++)
{
    tasks[nodeKey[i]] = Task.Run(() => ThreadMethod(nodeKey[i]));
}
```

Another option may to just add the tasks as-is, without any identifier, to a `List<Task>` or a `Task[]`:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
string[] nodeKeys;

for (int i = 0; i<nodeKeys.Length; i++)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => ThreadMethod(nodeKey[i])));
}
```

You may await an array of tasks using the [Task.WhenAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.7.2) method:

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
//or await Task.WhenAll(tasks.Values.ToArray());
```

Comment: I would think you'd have to copy the loop variable before the capture.